# smooth modular compactification of moduli of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Is there a smooth modular compactification of the moduli space of smooth curves of genus $ g > 1 $ over  $ \mathbb{C} $?

I am willing to allow for enrichments such as level structures. The compactification should be a projective variety rather than a stack. Any references are highly appreciated.

Comment: As comment: If $\bar \partial_J$ is transverse to zero section then $\mathcal M_{g,k}(M,g,\beta)$ will be smooth orbifold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure: see Eduard Looijenga, "Smooth Deligne-Mumford compactifications by means of Prym level structures", which completely answers your question.

There is also later work by de Jong-Pikaart, Boggi-Pikaart and Abramovich-Corti-Vistoli where more general non-abelian level structures are considered, and over more general base schemes.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{P}^3$ compactifies the moduli space of genus 2 curves with level 3 structure and the choice of an odd theta characteristic.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the details? 

Comment: for exemple here http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601251

there should be also a compactification for the event theta by van der geer (math ann in the 80s) but I can't rememeber if it is smooth